# xamarin form App refresh on background or minimized

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.forms, background-fetch

I need to refresh the application when push notification came at background. without opening push notification UI is not affecting .

Have anyone know how to update the application when its minimized where new update came. I have read Background fetch with perform fetch in xamarin forms but didn't get sufficient info anyone help please... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

UI actions must be performed on UI thread. If you want to make change on ui in background then you need to do it in MainThread like below:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (() => {
  labelNotificationCount.Text = "1";
});
```

For more information, [click here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread/p/System.Action/)

Comment: i didn't get this can you explain little bit where i can use this beginInvokeOnMainThread because when i click on the notification the only one field related to the notification changing on UI other notifications didnt changing without open every one of them.

Comment: @Riyas, Please share your ViewModel, Model and Xaml page.